# backgroundsetup is not working when using another tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, overleaf

I have a document with a backgroundsetup. When I use another tikzpicture on a page (e.g. a coordinate system), then the background picture is placed in the wrong position (see picture). It should be in the top right corner.
Has anyone a hint how to fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
....
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
color=black,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
   \node at ([xshift=18cm,yshift=-1cm] current page.north west)
        {\includegraphics[width = 7cm]{logo_minerva}}; %<- change the name of image
 \end{tikzpicture}}
}
.....
\newpage

\textbf{Aufgabe 6: Lineare Funktionen Textaufgabe}\hfill \textbf{6 Punkte}
\hrule
\relax
\vspace{1cm}
Eine Mathematikprüfung wird mit einer linearen Skala bewertet. Das Punktemaximum von 24 
Punkten entspricht der Note 6. Für 0 Punkte gibt es die Note 1.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
 axis lines=middle,
 axis line style={Stealth-Stealth, thick},
 xmin=-0.5,xmax=25,ymin=-0.5,ymax=8.5,
 xtick distance=6,
 ytick distance=1,
 xlabel=$Punkte$,
 ylabel=$Note$,
 title={Notenskala},
 grid=both,
 grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=darkgray!10},
 major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=darkgray!50},
 axis lines=middle
 ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: don't show only snippets. Always make a short but complete examples.

Comment: Don't use the background package. It is not work well when you use tikzpicture as the `contents={}`. Use `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{Your tikzpicture code}` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you wanted:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{mwe}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% background package setup %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
color=black,
position=current page.north west,
hshift=18cm,
vshift=-1cm,
contents={\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}
}


% Another method:
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Direct setup without background package %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\AddToHook{shipout/background}{
%\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
%\node at ([xshift=18cm,yshift=-1cm] current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}}; 
%\end{tikzpicture}
%}


\begin{document}
\textbf{Aufgabe 6: Lineare Funktionen Textaufgabe}\hfill \textbf{6 Punkte}
\hrule
\relax
\vspace{1cm}
Eine Mathematikprüfung wird mit einer linearen Skala bewertet. Das Punktemaximum von 24 
Punkten entspricht der Note 6. Für 0 Punkte gibt es die Note 1.
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
 axis lines=middle,
 axis line style={Stealth-Stealth, thick},
 xmin=-0.5,xmax=25,ymin=-0.5,ymax=8.5,
 xtick distance=6,
 ytick distance=1,
 xlabel=$Punkte$,
 ylabel=$Note$,
 title={Notenskala},
 grid=both,
 grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=darkgray!10},
 major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=darkgray!50},
 axis lines=middle
 ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: thanks a lot @Tom

Comment: You are welcome.